# Will the line right after the sync action notice the changes immediately?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

Saying that if dispatching an sync action in the block, will the line below it notice the change?

```js
// In a compoent connected to the reducer
class someComponent extends Component {

  const interuptOrNot = () => {
    this.props.dispatchChangeSomeStateAction({ payload: 2 })
  }

  render() {
    this.interuptOrNot()
    console.log(this.props.someState)
    return(<SomeComponent>)
  }

}
```

If the original props value from reducer equal to 1, what is the output info for the logger. 1 or 2? Or there is no output for the first render call, but it will output 2 for the re-render with newest state.

I know it is a bad idea to send action in render func, but what happen if I dispatch some actions changing the state of the reducer that component used?

What if dispatchChangeSomeStateAction dispatches a sync redux action to the reducer, and I call this function in the render function? Will the current render aborts because the state is out-of-date?

Answer (score 0):

```
    console.log(this.props.someState)
```

Will return 1.

The current render function will run with the current prop values.

When component's state changes [it will re-render.](https://lucybain.com/blog/2017/react-js-when-to-rerender/)

Use `componentWillReceiveProps` to track new/updated props.

[**Props are immutable**](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1260493/Immutability-in-React-and-Redux-The-Complete-Guide), if something updates them you track the changes in `componentWillReceiveProps` and pass updates to that component's state.